# Magento XML Google Shopping Secure URL

Tags: google-product-feeds, google-shopping, rss-feed

O.P.
Hi all,

I need to pull in the secure URL for the product in the Google PLA XML file

The current code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0"> 
<channel> 
<title>Data feed Title</title>
<link>http://www.website.com</link>
<description>Data feed description.</description>
<item>
<!-- Basic Product Information -->
<g:id>{sku}</g:id>
<title>{name,[substr],[70],[.]}</title>

<description>{description,[cleaner],[html_entity_decode],[strip_tags],[default],[{name}],[substr],[500],[.]}</description>

<g:google_product_category>1239</g:google_product_category>

{G:PRODUCT_TYPE,[10]}
<link>{url parent}</link>
{G:IMAGE_LINK}
<g:condition>new</g:condition>

<!-- Availability & Price -->
<g:availability>{is_in_stock?[in stock]:[out of stock]:[available for order]}</g:availability>
<g:price>{normal_price,[AUD],[0]}AUD</g:price>
{G:SALE_PRICE,[AUD],[0]}

<!-- Unique Product Identifiers-->

<? if("{brand}"=="") return '<g:brand>Discount Toy Co</g:brand>';
else return "<g:brand>{brand}</g:brand>" ; ?>

<g:gtin>{barcode}</g:gtin>
<g:mpn>{sku}</g:mpn>
<g:identifier_exists>TRUE</g:identifier_exists>

<!-- Apparel Products -->

<? if("{gender}"=="Girls") return '<g:gender>female</g:gender>';
if("{gender}"=="Boys") return '<g:gender>male</g:gender>';
else return '<g:gender>unisex</g:gender>' ;?>

<g:age_group>{age_group}</g:age_group>
<g:color>{color}</g:color>
<g:size>{size}</g:size>

<!-- Product Variants -->
{G:ITEM_GROUP_ID}
<g:material>{material}</g:material>
<g:pattern>{pattern}</g:pattern>

<!-- Shipping -->
<g:shipping_weight>{weight,[float],[2]}kg</g:shipping_weight>

<!-- AdWords attributes -->
<g:adwords_grouping>{adwords_grouping}</g:adwords_grouping>
<g:adwords_labels>{adwords_labels}</g:adwords_labels>
</item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

The {url parent} is INSECURE however the {G:IMAGE_LINK} gets pulled in as a secure image.

Anyone able to advise the shortcode for the secure URL?

Thanks,